# How to create Sub Domain with .htaccess php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to create sub domain using htaccess.
Currently my URL looks like this

> **`http://example.com/test.php?id=sub`**

. I want to change my URL as

> **`http://sub.example.com/test.php`**

Help me is any other way to solve this.

> I have tried following code but its not working

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com/test.php?id=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ([a-z0-9-]+)/? http://$1.example.com [R=301,NC,L]
```

Any one can help me.

Comment: htaccess alone can't magically make a subdomain. you need to properly configure your DNS records, as well as the parent host definition in apache.

Comment: You can use htaccess to create "Virtual" subdomains, you will also have to  use it to map the subdomains to respective folders. or through apache as Marc suggested, or if you have cPanel, you can login and try to create a subdoman; instead of giving it a name, put a `*` and your domain will accept any subdomain and route it to your main index, then use htaccess to catch all wild card subdomains and route them to folders.